# Navigation Menu Alighment CSS

Tags: css, alignment

I'd like to have my navigation menu on my [site](http://www.popglitch.com) span the width evenly. [Here](http://themeforest.net/item/halo-stunning-wordpress-portfolio-theme/full_screen_preview/256076) is an example of what I'm trying to accomplish, notice how the links are spaced evenly and stretch the entire width of the navigation bar.

I'm not exactly sure what code to use to accomplish this. I tried margin:auto but that didn't seem to work.

**Here is the CSS that I have:**

```
.mainNav{ 
  height:30px; 
  padding-bottom:0px; 
  margin:0 !important;
  position: relative; 
  border-top: 1px #d5d5d5 solid;
  border-bottom: 1px #d5d5d5 solid;
}
.mainNav a { 
  font-size:16px; 
  -webkit-transition:none; 
  -moz-transition:none; 
  -o-transition:none; 
  transition:none;
  position: relative;              
}   
.mainNav ul { 
  list-style-type: none; 
  list-style-image: none; 
}
.mainNav li {
  float:left;                   
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative; 
  list-style-type: none; 
  list-style-image: none; 
}   
.mainNav li a { 
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  padding:0 0 0 36px; 
  display:block; 
  padding-bottom:13px;  
}
.mainNav li ul { 
  display: none; 
  margin:0 !important; 
}
.mainNav li:hover > ul, .mainNav li.hover > ul { 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 35px; 
  left: 0; 
  z-index: 1000; 
  width: 180px; 
}
.mainNav li  > ul { 
  height:auto;  
  width: auto; 
  background: #fff; 
  border:1px solid #efefef; 
  padding:0; 
}
.mainNav li  > ul li {  
  width:180px; 
  padding: 0; 
  position: relative; 
  height:35px; 
  border-bottom:1px solid #efefef; 
}   
.mainNav li  > ul li:last-child{  
  border-bottom:none; 
}
.mainNav li  > ul li a { 
  text-transform:none; 
  height:22px; 
  padding: 5px 10px 0px 15px; 
  text-align: left;  
  font-size: 13px; 
  line-height:25px; 
  color:#333; 
}
.mainNav li  > ul li a:hover { 
  border:none; 
}
.mainNav li ul li:hover > ul, .mainNav li ul li.hover > ul { 
  display: block; 
  position: absolute; 
  top:0; 
  left: 180px; 
  z-index: 0; 
  width: 180px; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you turn off javascript and reload that wordpress theme that you want to replicate, you'll notice that the styling breaks.

That is because the margin's set on the list items to space them out evenly, is calculated using javascript and then applied.

You could write a javascript solution to style your list items or a quick fix would be to hard code the widths of the list items, **e.g**:

**Change your current block of CSS:**

```
.mainNav li a { 
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  padding:0 0 0 36px; 
  display:block; 
  padding-bottom:13px;  
}
```

**To the following:**

```
.mainNav li a { 
  text-transform:uppercase; 
  text-align: center; /*added*/
  width: 117px; /*added*/
  padding:0; /*edited*/
  display:block; 
  /*padding-bottom:13px;*/ /*removed*/
}
```

Comment: I tried it in firefox and chrome. For some reason the above CSS didn't affect the menu at all. Maybe something if overriding it, I'm not sure.

Comment: have a look at the revised answer. its a bit more blatent of what you have to change.

Comment: I can see that you have applied those styles now and the menu looks fine to me. what browser are you viewing it in?

Comment: I checked in chrome and firefox. The menu looks the same as it did before we changed the CSS. It's floating left with a lot of empty space after the last link instead of spread out evenly.

Comment: well I can see that it has been updated and looks fine. all I can think of is that your browser has cached the old styling. press `ctrl+F5` in the browser to give it a proper refresh.

Comment: That's what I thought initially but so I cleaned my cache and reloaded and it looked the same. Can you send me a screenshot of what you see?

Answer (score 0):

It looks fixed to me. Screenshot of your site in firefox, with applied styles seen in firebug:

[image]

Comment: Yeah I added a few more menus to get it in the middle, so I still have no idea how to get it to do what I want without based on however many menus I have. Like if I reduce it to 4 menus, I will need to change the width pixels again. I guess this is a quick fix until I figure it out.